# Hide all rows except header and last row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to setup a script that hides all my rows within a sheet except for the header and the last row. The script use to work but then I added a hidden row at the very top of the sheet and it stopped. I thought it would be an easy fix to just adjust the number to then start at the third row since the second row is now my frozen header, but it doesn't seem to work for me. The error I get is when I try to do sh.hideRow and it says "Those rows are out of bounds." for my variable destRange. I am assuming the issues is in my third parameter for the getRange, but I don't know what else it could be.

```js
// *****NOT WORKING*****
// HIDES ALL ROWS EXCEPT HEADER THEN UNHIDES LAST ROW
function HideRowsByQuarter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheetId').getSheets()
    .filter(function(sh) {
      return sh.getTabColor() == '#ff9901';
    }).forEach(function(sh) {
      var destRange = sh.getRange(3, sh.getMaxColumns(), sh.getLastRow());
      var unhideRow = sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 1)
      sh.hideRow(destRange);
      sh.unhideRow(unhideRow);
    })
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to hide all rows except for the 2 top rows and a last row in the sheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- 3rd argument of `getRange()` is the number of rows. In your script, `getRange(3, sh.getMaxColumns(), sh.getLastRow())` is used as the hide rows.

  - By this, the rows from top 3 row to last row + 2 are hidden.
  - You want to hide rows except for the last row.
  - So please modify to `getRange(3, sh.getMaxColumns(), sh.getLastRow() - 3)`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.
- By above modification, I think that it is not required to use `unhideRow()`.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
var destRange = sh.getRange(3, sh.getMaxColumns(), sh.getLastRow());
var unhideRow = sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 1)
sh.hideRow(destRange);
sh.unhideRow(unhideRow);
```

To:

```
var destRange = sh.getRange(3, sh.getMaxColumns(), sh.getLastRow() - 3);
sh.hideRow(destRange);
```

#### Reference:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows)

If this modification didn't resolve your issue, I apologize. At that time, in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide a sample spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information. I would like to modify the script.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly! I was confused on the last parameter of getRange but your explanation cleared it up perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: @Bryce Sinclair Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.